# Titanium Alloy Internationalization in Android - Not getting the string value

Tags: android, internationalization, titanium-alloy

The `Ti.Locale.getString('label_title') / L('label_title')` is **giving null on Android Simulator, It is working and giving me the exact title text in iOS though**. I am using the Alloy. Could anyone tell what is wrong or is it a bug of Titanium Alloy ?

My resource file is in /i18n/en/strings.xml, it looks like

```
<resources>
    <string name="labelTitle">Welcome to My App</string>
</resources>
```

and my login.js looks like

```
$.headingTitle.text = L("labelTitle");
```

login.xml looks like

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <Label id="headingTitle" />
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

login.tss is as follows

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor:"white"
},
"Label": {
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    color: "#000"
}
```

**I am using Titanium Studio SDK 3.1.3**

I have uploaded the project to google drive as zip Please find below the link

[My App](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2iPh_MZ_U4wN2tsdmxPZFJVSzA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **"textid"** instead of **"text"**.

If you want you can use tss files for internationalization :

```
 "#headingTitle":{
      textid:L('labelTitle'),
    },
```